# Why can't I access the visibleRect Property of an CALayer in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, calayer

I am having trouble doing this:

```
CALayer *myLayer = myUIImageView.layer; //works, no error from compiler
CGRect visRect = myLayer.visibleRect; //fat error, see below
```

The Error I get is:

> error: request for member
>   'visibleRect' in something not a
>   structure or union

but the documentation says:

> visibleRect 
>   Returns the visible region
>   of the receiver, in its own coordinate
>   space. (read-only) @property(readonly)
>   CGRect visibleRect

I have included QuartzCore.framework, CoreGraphics.framework, UIKit.framework, Foundation.framework.

So if that returns a CGRect, why doesn't it work? Any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm 99% sure you are missing the import statement.  It's not enough to just include the framework in your project.

I just tried this on a brand new project and it worked as expected.  The following is what I added to the ViewController.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CALayer *test_layer = self.view.layer;
    CGRect test_rect = test_layer.visibleRect;
    NSLog(@"%f, %f", test_rect.origin.x, 
          test_rect.size.width);
}
```

output was:

```
2009-04-21 17:53:55.999 Throwaway[72422:20b] 0.000000, 320.000000
```

Comment: you, sir or madam, are a saint.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks correct.  You aren't retaining anything, which could be dangerous, but technically isn't wrong.

the below message usually means that something is wrong with myLayer.

> `error: request for member 'visibleRect' in something not a structure or union`

Are you doing anything inbetween the two lines of code?

Inspect the myLayer object, make sure it's correct.  Also, confirm myUIImageView is initialized and not nil.

Also, try bypassing properties, by calling `[myLayer visibleRect];`

Comment: Thanks. How would I retain something there?

Comment: no way worked out... there is no code in between, and I do get a correct frame rectangle. I even change the position of that frame successfully. But can't get that visibleRect.